# Why did Blender start baking like this?

Tags: baking

Everything was working nicely: I baked the normal map and increased the detail with the normal map node, but now this is happening. Why?

[image]

Comment: did you try re-calculating normals?

Comment: Your render engine is Cycles, but you are viewing through Material Preview which uses eevee. Could this be responsible? Does switching to Rendered Preview help?

Comment: Also, it's just cut off at the bottom of your image, so I can't see. but make sure your Normal Map's color space is set to _Non-Color_.

Comment: Yes, it's set to non-color.

Comment: Re-calculating normals and viewing in rendered preview didn't help.

Comment: could you please share your file (also share the high poly)? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: It's only one object. I wanted to bake the displacement and normal textures into a single file with the right coordinates, but it does this now.

Comment: Under Bake -> Influence, space was set to object instead of tangent. That was the issue. Thansk for trying to help.